# How to calculate figure sizes

Tags: html, math

In html i have two figures, inner is transformed with css-transform/matrix
but it dimensions stays the same
i need to calculate dimensions of the figure with dotted line

[image]

Original figure is 300px width and 150px height, transform matrix is (0.8, -0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0, 0) or it is angle ~ -37°

figure with dotted line has dimensions 336 x 304

[html](http://jsfiddle.net/nu3m8/) how to make outer figure to wrap correctly the transformed inner figure? It is should be like on picture.

### HTML

```
<div style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 130px;
    border: 1px dotted #000;
">
    <div style="
    -webkit-transform: matrix(0.8, -0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
"></div>
</div>
```

If it can be wrapped i can simply calculate it dimensions.

or

[math] how can i calculate right dimensions of the figure with dotted line?

Comment: Simple trigonometry will give the you the appropriate sizes based on the inner dimensions and angle. JavaScript can do that for you.

Comment: yeah, but i'm sucks at math, unlike google,
finally i found an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="
    position: absolute;
    width:334px;height:302px;
    border: 1px dotted #000;
">
    <div style="
        transform:rotate(-37deg);
        top:75px;left:16px;position:relative;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
    ">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nu3m8/2/

Read for `transform:rotate` http://www.css3files.com/transform/ and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform

Comment: top and left attributes is not an answer,
the dimensions of the inner figure is different all the time.

Comment: For that you should use `transform-origin:x y;` Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: transform-origin can specified position of transformable element, but how I can find this values http://i.imgur.com/5lfAKiD.png ?